# Should myFunc = function(){} evaluate right away in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Leave a comment if I'm wrong: In my memory, I thought the difference between the two style of function creation:

```
function myFunc(){};
```

and

```
myFunc = function(){};
```

is the first evaluate right away, and the later waits for the function call.

so I got this code in [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable) about global variable is attach to window object:

```
function setGloabalVariable(){
  window.variable = '1';
}
```

after loading the page, why the variable still undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between these two types of declarations is that the first is a *named* function *statement*, the second is an *anonymous* function *expression*.  **Neither** of them is automatically executed at their point of declaration (you may be thinking of an IIFE).

```
// Create a symbol named "my_named_function"
// that points at the named function "my_named_function"
function my_named_function() {
}

// Create a symbol named "my_anonymous_func"
// that points to the *unnamed* function <anonymous function>
var my_anonymous_func = function() {
}
```

Both `my_named_function` and `my_anonymous_func` are unexecuted.  Both *may* be executed by calling them:

```
my_named_function();
my_anonymous_func();
```

An IIFE (Immediately Executed Function Expression) works a little differently:

```
(/* define a function */ function() {

})(/* and *immediately* execute it */);
```

I recommend reading through [kangax's excellent article on function expressions and statements](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) for more information on this subject.

Comment: Third case: `var my_variable = function with_a_name_too() { ... }`. `with_a_name_too` would be an identifier that's only visible within the function.

Comment: @Kay - Good point! However, it is also a little bit more wonky than either of the other two (not hoisted like a statement, and the function's name is not *supposed* to be available outside of the function's scope - [IE hoists it anyway](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs)).  I figured I'd leave that and function hoisting to another question / answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`function myFunc(){}` is a global function literal, it doesn't get "ran" right away, but it can be **forward & backward** referenced.  Meaning:

```
myFunc(); // this will run
function myFunc(){}
```

As in:

```
myFunc(); // this will **not** run
myFunc = function (){}
```

The difference with the second function, is that even though you hadn't declared a `var myFunc =` there. It becomes a global variable (also known as an inline anonymous function) , different from a global inline function, in that it has to be above sometihng (backward referenced) in order to be used.

```
function setGloabalVariable(){
    window.variable = '1'; 
    // this could have been written
    // variable = '1'; var variable = '1';
    // unless this function is called in some global scope, the closure won't
    // bring out this variable
}
```

An anonymous function is ran instantly, and I think that is what you're thinking of (but didn't have in your OP).

`(function () {  }());`

[Article on self-executing anonymous functions](http://briancrescimanno.com/2009/09/24/how-self-executing-anonymous-functions-work/)

Anonymous functions created a local/internal scope. Great for creating namespaces, and keeping things away from the global namespace.

Comment: In most cases `(function () { }())` is written `(function () { })()`.

Answer (score 0):

The named function is created and assigned at compile time, so it exists before the code start running. Example:

```
x(); // This works, as the function below already exists

function x() {}
```

The anonymous function may be created at compile time (depends on implementation), but the value is assigned to the variable at runtime. Example:

```
x(); // This doesn't work, as the value is not assigned yet

x = function(){};

x(); // Here it works
```

In both cases you have to actually call the function for the code inside the function to be executed.